# In Scalar DB, can I leave a Transaction as is if I don't need it or do I need to do some clean up

Tags: scalardb

The question is about Scalar DB (https://github.com/scalar-labs/scalardb). In the following code, I check if a user exists. If it does, I throw an exception. If it doesn't I go about adding it in tables. I am creating a DistributedTransaction instance at the beginning and am using it in all transactions.

```
val transaction: DistributedTransaction = transactionService.start
logger.trace("transaction started: " + transaction);
//Perform the operations you want to group in the transaction
val userExists:Boolean = userShouldNotExist(transaction,userKey)
if(!userExists) {
  userTransactionRepository.addUser(transaction, user)
  userProfileAndPortfolioTransactionRepository.addUserProfileAndPortfolio(transaction, user)
  userTokenTransactionRepository.addToken(transaction, emailToken, user)
  commitTransaction(transaction)
  (user: User, profileAndPortfolio: ExternalUserProfile, emailToken: UserToken)
} else {
  throw DuplicateUserException(user)
}
```

If the else block, do I need to do some cleanup/finalisation with DistributedTransaction or can I just leave it as is?

Answer (score 1):

You can basically leave it as it is.

Please note that even if `!userExists` returns true, the user could be created after the checking by another transaction.
In such case, commit will throw an exception.

Comment: Are saying that before the commit of the above code runs, if some other thread creates user with same parameters then this thread/transaction will fail?

Comment: Yes, snice both transactions try to create an initial record, which are conflicting.