# What happens if I start a transaction in ScalarDB but do not commit it?

Tags: scalardb

I am using ScalarDB to add ACID support in `Cassandra` application. What happens if I start a `Transaction` but don't commit it. Could there be any adverse effects of it?

Eg.

```
def somefunction=  {
    //Create the transaction
    val transaction: DistributedTransaction = transactionService.start
    if(all OK){
... //go ahead with DB operations
     commitTransaction(transaction) //OK
      (user: User, profileAndPortfolio: ExternalUserProfile, emailToken: UserToken)
    } else {
//miss commiting the transaction here
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is this duplicated with this ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63009148/in-scalar-db-can-i-leave-a-transaction-as-is-if-i-dont-need-it-or-do-i-need-to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be more correct, it might cause an anomaly (read skew anomaly or read-only transaction anomaly) if you use SERIALIZABLE with read-only transactions and use the read data.

So as a best practice, it is always better to call commit.

Comment: Thanks.Could you please explain what these anomalies are?

Comment: There are commonly know anomalies in database systems.
So you can easily find what they are.

https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-read-and-write-skew-phenomena/

https://www.cs.umb.edu/~poneil/ROAnom.pdf

Comment: Is it safe to use `abort()`? I recently hit a scenario where an application error happened but because I always call commit transaction, the wrong data got entered in the DB. Also, yours and @yuji's advice seem opposite. Which one is the correct one (always call commit or call abort in case of error)?

Answer (score 0):

There is no effect. All mutations in a transaction are stored in the client's memory until the commit. Other transactions cannot see them and the datastore (Cassandra) doesn't receive any request for the mutations.